# Laravel helpers loaded twice

Tags: php, laravel, autoload, helper

So, I have a Laravel app with a custom helpers. Everything works fine until I run

```
php artisan route:cache
```

I got an error:

```
[Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException]                                                           
  Cannot redeclare getProperty() (previously declared in /Users/xxxx/xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx/a  
  pp/Helpers/getProperty.php:4)
```

The helpers are loaded with HelperServiceProvider:

```
class HelperServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    public function register()
    {
        require base_path().'/app/Helpers/getProperty.php';
    }
}
```

The HelperServiceProvider is registered in config/app.php providers list:

```
'providers'=>[
 // ...
  App\Providers\HelperServiceProvider::class
];
```

I patched the issue by wrapping my helper with function_exists('getProperty') condition. However it does not seems the right way to do

Any ideas why Laravel is trying to load my helper twice?